# Doubt in the proof of Mcduff''s method of probes

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, toric-varieties, symplectic-topology

I have been reading the paper "Displacing Lagrangian toric fibers by probes" by Dusa Mcduff, here is the arxiv link https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.1686.pdf.
I have a doubt in the proof of lemma $2.4$ where the method of probes is introduced. Basically my main question is that I'm not sure why we are able to obtain a Darboux chart around the pre-image of the set $\Phi^{-1}(p)$. I get that we can do that locally around each point, and even around every lagrangian tori $\Phi^{-1}(c)$ because of the equivariant Darboux theorem, however I'm not sure why we are able to extend them along a line given by the probe. Do we really need the
torus action for this ? Because otherwsie wouldn't this work for any hamiltonian action of a lie group $G$ on a compact connected symplectic manifold of dimension $2$ since the image of the moment polytope here would be an interval ?

Any insight is appreaciated. Thanks in advance.